# Looping a Function In Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.6

I have a Function used against multiple devices listed in a LIST. It throws the error if it doesn't work against a particular devices and the script breaks.

```
def macGrabber(child,switch,cat = False):
    try:
        if cat is False:
            child.expect('.#')
            child.sendline('sh mac address-table | no-more')
        else:
            child.sendline('sh mac address-table dynamic | i Gi')
        child.expect('.#', timeout=3000)
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        print child.before,child.after
        child.close()
        raise
    macs = child.before
    child.close()
    macs = macs.splitlines()
    print('Connection to %s CLOSED' % switch)
    return macs
```

1. Can we loop it ( retry multiple times ) before it goes to "Except' ? OR
2. Can we skip it and try for next device if it fails ?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, yes, you can retry multiple times.  Keep an error counter, wrap the whole `try/except` in a loop, and when you get an exception check the error counter and keep looping if it's less than (say) 5, otherwise raise the error as you're already doing.

```
error_count = 0
while True:
    try:
        if cat is False:
            child.expect('.#')
            child.sendline('sh mac address-table | no-more')
        else:
            child.sendline('sh mac address-table dynamic | i Gi')
        child.expect('.#', timeout=3000)
        break
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        ++error_count
        if error_count < 5:
            continue
        print child.before,child.after
        child.close()
        raise
```

For the second question, yes, you can skip the device if it fails by just putting `return None` in the except handling.  But you also would need to adjust the calling code to properly handle a `None` result.

Comment: it says invalid Syntax :error_count++
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oops, it should be `++error_count`, not `error_count++`.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `macGrabber` inside a `try...except` block and call `continue` if you would like to continue looping without the program crashing.

```
multiple_devices = [
    (child1, switch1, cat1),
    (child2, switch2, cat2),
    ...,
]

for device in multiple_devices:
    try:
        macGrabber(*device)

    except pexpect.TIMEOUT as e:
        print(f'{device} timed out')
        print(e)
        continue  #  <--- Keep going!
```